# Character Counting within a loop

Tags: intersystems-cache, mumps, intersystems-cache-studio

Instead of using hardcoded calls like I did in the code below, is it possible to have use a WRITE command within a For Loop to print out number of times each character is used? Below is what I have written, which will give me "A=n" but what I would like would be "A=n","B=n" etc without it being hardcoded.

```
 CHARCOUNT
 n str
 f  r !,"Enter patient's name: ",str q:str=""  d
 . s ^XPTNAME(str)=""
 w #
 f  s str=$O(^XPTNAME(str)) q:str=""  w !,"A = ",$L(str,"A") 
 q
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want to achieve but below some ideas.

`COUNT()
        N array,char,key
        S key=""
        F  S key=$O(^ZNAME(key)) Q:key=""  D    ; loop through all keys
        .       S char=""
        .       F I=1:1:$L(key)  D              ; loop through all letters
        ..              S char=$E(key,I)        ; extract the letter
        ..              S array(char)=$G(array(char))+1 ; increment count
        S char=""
        F  S char=$O(array(char)) Q:char=""  D
        .       W char,"=",array(char),!
        Q`

Testing in GTM:

```
GTM>ZWR ^ZNAME
^ZNAME("first,last")="Second Street"
^ZNAME("name,surname")="First Street"

GTM>d COUNT^ZZTEST
,=2
a=3
e=2
f=1
i=1
l=1
m=2
n=2
r=2
s=3
t=2
u=1
```

Although if you have Mixed case it can get different than you expect:

```
GTM>ZWR ^ZNAME
^ZNAME("FIRST,LAST")=""
^ZNAME("first,last")="Second Street"
^ZNAME("name,surname")="First Street"

GTM>d COUNT^ZZTEST
,=3
A=1
F=1
I=1
L=1
R=1
S=2
T=2
a=3
e=2
f=1
i=1
l=1
m=2
n=2
r=2
s=3
t=2
u=1
```

For this see the below code that may be specific to GTM ($ZCO function), also able to handle arrays or globals with limitation to single key/subscription:

Code (Attention that using arrays with name of the variable used internally in this label will not work, example "array","char","key","upper","where" since they will be newed):

```
COUNTV2(where,upper)
        N array,char,key
        I $G(where)="" Q
        ; loop through all keys
        F  S where=$Q(@where) Q:where=""  D
        .       S char=""
        .       S key=$E(where,$F(where,"("),$L(where)-1)
        .       I $E(key)="""" S key=$E(key,2,$L(key)-1)
        .       I $G(upper) S key=$ZCO(key,"U") ; Convert to uppercase
        .       F I=1:1:$L(key)  D              ; loop through all letters
        ..              S char=$E(key,I)        ; extract the letter
        ..              S array(char)=$G(array(char))+1 ; increment count
        S char=""
        F  S char=$O(array(char)) Q:char=""  D
        .       W char,"=",array(char),!
        Q
```

Tested with global:

```
GTM>ZWR ^ZNAME
^ZNAME("FIRST,LAST")=""
^ZNAME("first,last")="Second Street"
^ZNAME("name,surname")="First Street"

GTM>D COUNTV2^ZZTEST("^ZNAME",1)
,=3
A=4
E=2
F=2
I=2
L=2
M=2
N=2
R=3
S=5
T=4
U=1
```

Tested with array:

```
GTM>zwr array2
array2(12)=""
array2("First")=""
array2("lasT")=""

GTM>D COUNTV2^ZZTEST("array2",1)
1=1
2=1
A=1
F=1
I=1
L=1
R=1
S=2
T=2
```

Disabling force upper case:

```
GTM>D COUNTV2^ZZTEST("^ZNAME",0)
,=3
A=1
F=1
I=1
L=1
R=1
S=2
T=2
a=3
e=2
f=1
i=1
l=1
m=2
n=2
r=2
s=3
t=2
u=1
```

If you want additional logic to include only character A to Z:

```
GTM>W $A("A")
65
GTM>W $A("Z")
90
GTM>S char=","

GTM>I ($A(char)>64)&($A(char)<91) w char

GTM>s char="A"

GTM>I ($A(char)>64)&($A(char)<91) w char
A
GTM>S char="f"

GTM>I ($A(char)>64)&($A(char)<91) w char

GTM>s char="Z"

GTM>I ($A(char)>64)&($A(char)<91) w char
Z
```

Answer (score 3):

[$length](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.clshttp://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_flength) counts parts which delimeted by second argument. In this case you may use [$char](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.clshttp://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_fchar) and [$ascii](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.clshttp://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_fascii).